# Adjusting Sec Axis to Match Primary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm unable to lower the sec axis to just 0. I suspect it's in the way I'm transforming the sec axis maybe. Primary axis should always be using it's min value, while sec axis should always start at 0, never negative. How should I approach this?

```
library(dplyr)   # or library(magrittr), %>%
library(scales)  # rescale
library(ggplot2)

# ex. data 
constructive::construct(stats)

stats <- data.frame(
  Snapshot.Date = as.Date(c("2020-09-30", "2020-12-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-06-30", "2021-09-30", "2021-12-31")),
  avg_asking_rate = c(
    4.93799293627304, 4.99132174488857, 4.97053998470495, 4.90321494004932,
    4.93494348159945, 4.91379691657121
  ),
  vacancy_rate = c(
    9.94185919399802, 11.5989188611645, 12.9308555110482, 13.9590437469142,
    13.5155036299108, 12.8472483323431
  )
)

# transform secondary axis to primary
train_sec <- function(primary, secondary, na.rm = TRUE) {
  from <- range(secondary, na.rm = na.rm)
  to   <- range(primary, na.rm = na.rm)
  forward <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = from, to = to)
  }
  reverse <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = to, to = from)
  }
  list(fwd = forward, rev = reverse)
}

# lower min by multiples of 0.5 only for primary axis
y_lm <- floor((min(stats$avg_asking_rate))*2)/2

# use train_sec function
sec <- with(stats, train_sec(stats$avg_asking_rate, stats$vacancy_rate))

stats %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = `Snapshot.Date`, y = avg_asking_rate))+
  ggtitle("Rent") +
  geom_col(aes(fill = "Avg. Asking Rate"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = sec$fwd(vacancy_rate), colour =  "Vacancy Rate"), size = 1) +
  
  scale_x_date(name = NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~sec$rev(.), name = "Vacancy Rate"))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(y_lm,NA)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = c("Avg. Asking Rate" = "blue", "Vacancy Rate" = "green"),
                    guide = guide_legend(order = 1))+
  scale_colour_manual(name = NULL, values = c("Vacancy Rate" = "green"), guide = guide_legend())
```

Expected output for scaling I'm aiming for would look like:

[image: output]

Comment: Your `train_sec` is finding the transformation to make the min/max of the secondary series match the min/max of the primary axis. It sounds like you want it to match the range `(4.5, max(avg_asking_rate))` not  `(min(avg_asking_rate), max(avg_asking_rate))`.

Comment: Probably you want to look at the `breaks` arguments.

Comment: @JonSpring setting the range to 4.5 works in getting rid of the negative values for the sec axis, but the sec axis starts at it's own min instead of 0.  I guess bc it's tied to the primary there would be no way in getting the sec axis to start at 0 like in the image I provided?